# Karate API call with .pem file

Tags: karate, pem

I have an api request which needs a .pem file to be sent with it to get the response. I have configured the same in the Insomnia tool and i am able to get response for that. When i try to setup the same request in karate it fails with the response bad certificate error.
Insomnia curl :

```
curl --request POST \
  --url https://tokengenerator.com:8443/as/token.oauth2 \
  --header 'Cookie: PF=TmfprifldGj2sxCzWs3qYd; PF=TmfprifldGj2sxCzWs3qYd' \
  --header 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \
  --cookie PF=TmfprifldGj2sxCzWs3qYd \
  --data username=username \
  --data password=password \
  --data = \
  --data grant_type=password \
  --data client_id=TOKENCLIENT
```

and I have added the .pem file in insomnia request [image: insomnia .pem file addition]

in karate feature file the request is below:

```
Background:

    * configure ssl = true

  Scenario: Token Generation - Success Response

    Given url 'https://tokengenerator.com:8443/as/token.oauth2'

    And header Content-Type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

    And form field client_id = 'TOKENCLIENT'

    And form field grant_type = 'password'

    And form field username = 'username'

    And form field password = 'password'

    When method POST

    Then status 200
```

In karate config i have added the details for .pem file as:

```
var config = {
    env: env,

    CERT_FILE: 'src/test/resource/Client.pem',
};

karate.configure('ssl', {
    keyStore: config.CERT_FILE,
    keyStorePassword: 'password',
    keyStoreHost: 'hostname.intranet:8443',
    keyStoreType: 'pkcs12',
    trustAll: true,
    algorithm: 'TLS'
})
```

Error i am getting in karate is :

**ERROR com.intuit.karate - javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Received fatal alert: bad_certificate, http call failed after 639 milliseconds for url: https://tokengenerator.com:8443/as/token.oauth2**

Comment: yes, pem file setup can be tricky as you have to get the format and path right. my only suggestion is refer to the examples and troubleshoot: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/tree/master/karate-demo/src/test/java/ssl or help others replicate the problem: https://github.com/karatelabs/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the .pem file to .p12 and it worked

```
var config = {
        env: env,
        TRUST_STORE: 'classpath:keystore.jks',
        CERT_FILE: 'classpath:Client.p12',
    };

karate.configure('ssl', {
    keyStore: config.CERT_FILE,
    keyStorePassword: 'password',
    keyStoreType: 'pkcs12',
    trustAll: true,
    algorithm: 'TLS'
})
```